# Android emulator won't shut down in Android Studio (I don't see "Stop" under the Actions Tab of AVD Manager)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, virtual-device-manager, android-device-manager

From looking this up online, I should have a "Stop" option under the Actions Tab of the Device Manager's tool window?

But I only see six options: Duplicate, Wipe Data, Cold Boot Now, Show On Disk, Details, Delete.

Seems the only way I have to stop it is by holding down the (virtual) power button to then shut it down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the emulator opened in Android studio by pressing the power off button or close(x) button(adjacent to your emulator name) on the horizontal tool menu above emulator. See image
[image]

Comment: It seems rectangle button is navigation button

Comment: Sorry, my bad (that's redundant GUI). Have retracted the down-vote.

Comment: This does not stop the emulator, only turns of screen? 
Trying to use an adb feature to connect to a connected device but it wont run if multiple devices are running

Answer (score 1):

Only closing the emulator window with (x) works for me. Pressing the power off button just turns of the screen. The ADB manual in android developer says there should be a "Stop" in device manager but that is removed.

[image: emulator]